# Specifying in QueryDSL that a result will be unique

Tags: java, querydsl

I have a table book, and then a table book_edition keeping track of the editions of the book.

```
-----------------------------------------
| book_id | edition | edition_date |
| 5       | 1       | 2013-02-01   |
| 5       | 2       | 2014-01-25   |
-----------------------------------------
```

book_id is a foreign key into the book table. book_id and edition are the composite primary key of the book_edition table. I want to retrieve the edition date of the latest edition for a certain book, using QueryDSL. This is a sub-query which contributes to a larger query. It seems like it should be straightforward, but so far the only way I can figure to do it is this:

```
NumberExpression<Integer> maxEdition = new SQLSubQuery().from(SBookEdition.bookEdition)
                   .where(SBookEdition.bookEdition.bookId.eq(SBook.book.id))
                   .unique(SBookEdition.bookEdition.edition.max());
Expression<Date> bookDate =  new SQLSubQuery().from(SBookEdition.bookEdition)
                   .where(SBookEdition.bookEdition.bookId.eq(SBook.book.id),SBookEdition.bookEdition.edition.eq(maxEdition))
                   .unique(SBookEdition.bookEdition.editionDate.max())
                   .as(new PathBuilder<>(Date.class, column.getAlias()));
```

It seems like there must be a simpler way, and one that does not require asking for the "max" of something I know to be unique, because it is a primary key.

Comment: I also can't directly think of a different way. I created a ticket for subquery naming https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/687